# Refactor IQueryable and IEnumerable that share the same condition

Tags: c#, iterator

I have extension methods to encapsulate query conditions, however I have to separate `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable`. Is there any way I can reduce the redundancy and still not lose the performance benefit of `IQueryable`?

```
public static class PAYTRACK_PARTNER_Extension 
{
    public static IQueryable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> WhereInPayer(this IQueryable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> query, int payerId)
    {
        var result = query.Where(q => q.payer_id == payerId);
        return result;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> WhereInPayer(this IEnumerable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> query, int payerId)
    {
        var result = query.Where(q => q.payer_id == payerId);
        return result;
    }

    public static IQueryable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> WhereInPayee(this IQueryable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> query, int payeeId)
    {
        var result = query.Where(q => q.payee_id == payeeId);
        return result;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> WhereInPayee(this IEnumerable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> query, int payeeId)
    {
        var result = query.Where(q => q.payee_id == payeeId);
        return result;
    }


    public static IQueryable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> WhereIsNotApproved(this IQueryable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> query)
    {
        var result = query.Where(q => q.partner_is_approve.GetValueOrDefault(false).Equals(false));
        return result;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> WhereIsNotApproved(this IEnumerable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> query)
    {
        var result = query.Where(q => q.partner_is_approve.GetValueOrDefault(false).Equals(false));
        return result;
    }

    public static PAYTRACK_PARTNER SingleByPayerAndPayee(this IQueryable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> query, int payerId, int payeeId)
    {
        var result = query.Single(q => q.payer_id == payerId && q.payee_id == payeeId);
        return result;
    }

    public static PAYTRACK_PARTNER SingleByPayerAndPayee(this IEnumerable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> query, int payerId, int payeeId)
    {
        var result = query.Single(q => q.payer_id == payerId && q.payee_id == payeeId);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `IQueryable<T>` everywhere, because you can convert to it from `IEnumerable<T>` by using [`AsQueryable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb507003.aspx):

```
public static IQueryable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> WhereInPayer(
    this IQueryable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> query, int payerId)
{
    var result = query.Where(q => q.payer_id == payerId);
    return result;
}

public static IEnumerable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> WhereInPayer(
     this IEnumerable<PAYTRACK_PARTNER> query, int payerId)
{
     return query.AsQueryable().WhereInPayer(payerId);
}
```

Also, names in ALL_CAPS are not commonly used in C#, you should adopt c# naming conventions.

Comment: thank you :) i can't change to all cap though because it is dbml generated from db and they named it like that.

Comment: I can't convert it in linq to entity.
like company.T_RFQs when T_RFQs is entity set.
i just can't convert to by asQueryable. compiler said it is not support :(